# Web services in Drupal

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How Drupal can read the external web services? example:

this web service xml:

"www.mysite.com/dabs/xml_view/xml/bank_id:10/updated:1".

[image]

this link is a web services xml, I want to consume it in drupal.

I found drupal can create Web services from its contents, but I do not know how he read the other webservices.

how drupal can read, modify those tags, put, post, delete  ..... ??

Answer (score 1):

Usually, consuming a Web Service requires developing a client application. In the case of a Drupal site, it should be done a Drupal custom module. Except for the integration of custom code in Drupal and usage of its API/mechanism to display information on pages, store them, etc. this would standard PHP coding.

There is also two module that are supposed to help you with that, or even remove the need to develop a custom module. Unfortunately, they both have the same name: Web service client. One is https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient, the other is https://www.drupal.org/project/clients.

The actual complexity will likely be in consuming the service properly. For that, you need good understanding on usage of XML and HTTP Requests, and preferably good documentation of the web service (incl. data format and meaning of the various values in the XML).

Answer (score 0):

Use web service client module in drupal

https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient